# PHP regular expression returns two empty array

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get the content within td tags from html,

```
<?php
 $link = $_POST['link'];
 $data = file_get_contents($link);

 //echo $data;
 $regex ='"!<td>(.*?)</td>!is"';;
 preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
 var_dumP($matches);    
?>
```

it seems it can get the result, but when I var_dump it, it only have the following result,

```
array (size=2)
0 => 
array (size=0)
  empty
1 => 
array (size=0)
  empty
```

it seems can get the something from the regular expression, but the array is empty, cannot show the html content in it. Anything wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: can you share the string on which you are checking?

Comment: Actually, I want use regex to get the question part of stackoverflow post. the queestion seems within <td class="postcell">